# Google contacts API limits

Tags: javascript, android, oauth, google-contacts-api

I am unable to get any information on the daily limits for Google Contacts API. There was a 2011 post on the salesforce thread that said it's 200,000 per day. Could anybody confirm if it is indeed 200,000/day or unlimited?

Got the answer. It's 20,000,000 requests.

Just attaching a link for request limits for other google services

http://wiki.glitchdata.com/index.php?title=Google_API

Answer (score 0):

its Courtesy limit: 20,000,000 requests/day. You could see this by registering freely in google developer site https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/.